# Query where there is at least 1 association, but return all

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

I have created this record which you can see has 2 tags - tag1, and tag2

```
{
  "id": "d87de1d9-b048-4867-92fb-a84dca59c87e",
  "name": "Test Name",
  "tags": [
    {
      "id": "fa0ca8fd-eff4-4e58-8bb0-a1ef726f01d4",
      "name": "tag1",
      "organizationId": "d87de1d9-b048-4867-92fb-a84dca59c87e",
      "updatedAt": "2018-12-05T18:53:56.867Z",
      "createdAt": "2018-12-05T18:53:56.867Z"
    },
    {
      "id": "66e758af-9907-4278-8c4f-f8fb2bf9aea9",
      "name": "tag2",
      "organizationId": "d87de1d9-b048-4867-92fb-a84dca59c87e",
      "updatedAt": "2018-12-05T18:53:56.867Z",
      "createdAt": "2018-12-05T18:53:56.867Z"
    }
  ],
  "updatedAt": "2018-12-05T18:53:56.860Z",
  "createdAt": "2018-12-05T18:53:56.860Z"
}
```

I want to write a query that looks for an organization that contains `tag1` and returns that entire organization including all of the tags.

I currently have this query which only returns the tag record for which matches the query rather than all the tags.

```
db.organization.findAll({
  include: {
    model: db.tag,
    where: { name: 'tag1' }
  }
})
```

and it's producing this result

```
[
  {
    "id": "3d03d74e-82ec-485e-aa29-abe9e8b0f0e9",
    "name": "Test Name",
    "createdAt": "2018-12-05T19:29:40.685Z",
    "updatedAt": "2018-12-05T19:29:40.685Z",
    "tags": [
      {
        "id": "75dc9cd2-5e20-4aa6-b86e-cbaa2c896d57",
        "name": "tag1", <-- NOTE THAT ONLY TAG1 IS IN THE RESULTS EVEN THOUGH THERE SHOULD BE ANOTHER TAG OBJECT RETURNED
        "createdAt": "2018-12-05T19:29:40.694Z",
        "updatedAt": "2018-12-05T19:29:40.694Z",
        "organizationId": "3d03d74e-82ec-485e-aa29-abe9e8b0f0e9"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

How can I write a query to do this?

Answer (score 8):

I search a lot about this subject and I think the most efficient way to do it (in this case) is to have a basic association for filtering and one to receive your data

**Associations file**

```
// This is for filtering
organization.hasMany(tag, {
  foreignKey: 'organizationId',
});

// This one is for receiving data after filtering
organization.hasMany(tag, {
  foreignKey: 'organizationId',
  as: 'tags',
});
```

**Controller**

```
const results = await db.organization.findAll({
  include: [{
    model: db.tag,
    where: { name: 'tag1' },
    attributes: [], // remove 'Tag' property from results
  }, {
    model: db.tag,
    as: 'tags',
  }],
});

console.log(results);
```

The `console.log(results);` will return:

```
[
  {
    "id": "...",
    "name": "Organization Test Name",
    "createdAt": "...",
    "updatedAt": "...",
    // "Tag": [ // This property was removed by 'attributes: []'
    //   {
    //     "id": "...",
    //     "name": "tag1",
    //     "organizationId": "..."
    //     "createdAt": "...",
    //     "updatedAt": "...",
    //   },
    // ],
    "tags": [
      {
        "id": "...",
        "name": "tag1",
        "organizationId": "..."
        "createdAt": "...",
        "updatedAt": "...",
      },
      {
        "id": "...",
        "name": "tag1",
        "organizationId": "..."
        "createdAt": "...",
        "updatedAt": "...",
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Some resources from GitHub: [Can't exclude association's fields from select statement in sequelize #3664](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/8754)

Answer (score 4):

**Patchy way to do this is :**

```
tag.belongsTo(organization, {as: 'AllTags', foreignKey : 'organization_id' }); 
// --- Add another association with alias ----- 

db.organization.findAll({
    include: [{
        model: db.tag,
        where: { name: 'tag1' }
    },{
        model: db.tag,
        as : 'AllTags' //<----- HERE
    }]
})
```

Answer (score 2):

what you want to do is perform a **right join** on tables `Organization` and `Tag` but what you are actually doing is an **inner join** (read more about joins [here](http://www.sql-join.com/sql-join-types/))

sequelize doesn't support right joins (see closed feature request [here](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/4187))

the way I see it, you can either:

- <s>run a raw sql query (bad option)</s>
- perform aggregation via sequelize and filter results using node (ok option)

---

```
const orgs = await db.organization.findAll({
  include: {
    model: db.tag,
  }
});

const result = orgs.filter(org => org.tags.some(tag => tag.name === 'tag1'))
```

Comment: This would not be a right join in SQL, it would require a subselect.